# Is it possible to run PHP script automatically after some time?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm working on a scheduling app using JS and PHP, this app shows a calendar to the user with the option to click on some time period to select it, when some user selects a time period, I'm saving this time period as UNAVAILABLE to other users, just to prevent overbooking.

I'm changing the status of the time period to UNAVAILABLE right on the user click into the calendar, this way, if another user opens this calendar, the time period will be UNAVAILABLE preventing its click.

After the user's click, I'm using JS to start a count down just to restore that time period to AVAILABLE again.

My dilemma is if the user closes the browser without finishing the checkout, the time period will continue with UNAVAILABLE status because of that JS count down will be lost.

So, my question is, is it possible to restore that status via PHP automatically after some time?

Thanks for any suggestion here.

Comment: Yes its called a CRON job, look it up https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Answer (score 0):

There is such a thing as a "planner" or "task manager" on Unix platforms, it's called Cron. To do your task you need to create a job (task)in cron, that will open the desired page with the desired parameters on certain period, like:

"curl [http://smth.here.com/cron.php?ilikebigbutts"](http://smth.here.com/cron.php?ilikebigbutts%22)

you need to install curl for that of course

Comment: Hello Undry, thanks for your reply.

You are suggesting Cron like @RiggsFolly sad above, maybe Cron should be the solution here, but I have to create that task dynamically, I mean, when some customer schedule a time slot on agenda.

I'll take a look on that way,

Thanks.

Comment: That's not important. What you need to is to have the logic on the server side PHP, e.g. check all schedules. So you invoke your page once every 5 minutes e.g., if there are appointments you do your things, if not script exits